# Найти минимальный элемент и его номер в двумерном масиве

Tags: c++, массивы, codeblocks

Пишу на с++, не разберусь по какой формуле найти можно номер минимального элемента. В моем случае это переменная index

Сам код вот. Как находить номер??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,i,low,index,m,j;
    cout << "SIZE = ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "SIZE = ";
    cin >> m;
    int **a=new int*[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {a[i]=new int[m];}
        if(!a){cout << ("ERROR");return 123;}
    cout << ("INPUT ARR = \n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for( j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
         cin >> a[i][j];
        }

    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for( j=0; j<m; j++)
        {cout << a[i][j] << " ";}
        cout << endl;}
    getch();
    low = a[0][0];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
         if(low>=a[i][j])
        {
            low=a[i][j];
        }
        else j++;
        }

    }
    cout << low << endl;
    cout << index << endl;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    delete []a[n];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас проверка выделения памяти не на месте - вы проверяете `if (!a)` уже после того, как с этим `a` работали. Только это все равно неважно, потому что раз вы используете `new`, а не `new(std::nothrow)`, то если не хватит памяти, он не вернет нулевой указатель, а сгенерирует исключение. Так что эта проверка лишняя.

Номер элемента в друмерном массиве определяется двумя индексами, а не одним, так что я бы делал так:

```
int i_min = 0, j_min = 0, no = 0;
int low = a[0][0];
int no_min = 0;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++, no++) {
        if (low > a[i][j]) {
            low = a[i_min = i][j_min = j];
            no_min = no;
        }
    }
}

cout << "Min[" << i_min << "][" << j_min
     << "] #" << no_min << " = " low << endl;
```

Некий номер `no` добавил по совету из ответа avp, но, по-моему, говорить об одном номере нельзя - все равно ведь у вас не настоящий двухмерный массив, и в памяти числа располагаются не подряд.

Answer (score 0):

Например, заведите переменную `ix = 0` и увеличивайте ее во внутреннем цикле.

Каждый раз, когда вы в нем присваиваете новое значение `low` пишите и `index = ix;`

А вообще, если вас интересует именно формула, то номер (начиная с 0) *`i,j`*-го элемента матрицы вычисляется как `i * m + j` (где `m` это количество столбцов, другими словами граница для индекса `j`)